# Wrong query plan for GIN index

Tags: execution-plan, index-tuning, performance-tuning, postgresql-14

I have the following [repeatable case](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jJRCGNv2XDARm9vdNnLRGC/3).

I have an `uuid[]` column with a `gin` index, which stores all unqiue `uuid`s, without doubles and repeats.

Test table:

```
CREATE TABLE test 
    (
    id serial not null, 
    uuid uuid[]
    );

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS gin_uuid_idx
    ON test 
    USING gin(uuid);
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM "table_name" 
WHERE "uuid" && ARRAY['9070bc76-10b1-420a-b823-13f09ac637a2']::uuid[];
```

Query plan:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on test (cost=1500.97..3199.83 rows=1157 width=36) (actual time=2.359..2.360 rows=1 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: (uuid && '{9070bc76-10b1-420a-b823-13f09ac637a2}'::uuid[])
  Heap Blocks: exact=1
  -> Bitmap Index Scan on gin_uuid_idx (cost=0.00..1500.68 rows=1157 width=0) (actual time=2.353..2.354 rows=1 loops=1)
       Index Cond: (uuid && '{9070bc76-10b1-420a-b823-13f09ac637a2}'::uuid[])

Planning Time: 0.519 ms
Execution Time: 2.387 ms
```

Expected rows(1157 rows) doesnt equals real rows (expect 1 row), and planner selects non-optimal query plan.

For large tables with 10-100KK rows, query will be executing for 10-30 seconds, which is too long.

How can I fix this wrong behavior and make the query run faster?